# mysqli bind_param - avoid listing them all

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this bind_param statement - and it works, but its ugly

```
$record-> bind_param($sss, 
$fieldNameValues[0],
$fieldNameValues[1],
$fieldNameValues[2],
$fieldNameValues[3],
$fieldNameValues[4],
etc
$fieldNameValues[10],
$fieldNameValues[11]
);
```

$sss is just equal to "sss...s" and seems to work fine

I want to put an array (or a loop) or something into the bind_param statement instead of all the $fieldNameValues[x] ... but I can't seem to make it work

Any tips please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call the `bind_param()` method with the given array as arguments.

When you use [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) you can use the `execute()` method to provide the values for the prepared statement.